# pure C++ vs Managed C++

Tags: visual-c++

How to build pure C++ application so that it doesn't have any dependencies? i am using VS 2008. I mean, dependencies like dotnetfx framework, etc, other things required by managed C++ programs.

Comment: What? That sentence doesn't parse. I think it's missing a verb.

Comment: Also: "doesn't have any dependencies"? What about the operating system? Common libraries? Aren't those allowed?

Answer (score 2):

I think as long as you're not using the `/clr` compiler flag in any way you'd be ok. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28VS.80%29.aspx) for an article about compiling native C++ programs.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have the following setting in your general project options **No Common Language Runtime support**. The project is build without /CLR switch, so there is no .NET framework in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a **native** C++ project - that does not use the .NET framework then you want to create a new Win32 project.

Goto File -> new project choose **Win32** project (either console or windows) it's located under "other languages" -> "Visual C++"